# Compartir una imagen cogida desde un array de imagenes en android

Tags: android-intent, android-viewpager, arrayadapter

Quisiera compartir la imagen vista en ese mismo instante en el **ViewPager**, la cual sera cogida desde un array de imágenes nombrado **sliderImagesId**.

Aqui los archivos de la app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPageAndroid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="330dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:maxWidth="39dip"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSharePhoto"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/share"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF4081"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="sharePhoto"
        android:text="foto" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Primera clase**(archivo java).

```
public class AndroidImageSlider extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.android_image_slider_activity);


    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPageAndroid);
    AndroidImageAdapter adapterView = new AndroidImageAdapter(this);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapterView);


    // listeners of our two buttons
    View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.buttonSharePhoto:
                    sharePhoto();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    // our buttons
    findViewById(R.id.buttonSharePhoto).setOnClickListener(handler);

}


private void sharePhoto() {



    // aqui codigo para compartir foto.


}
```

}

**Segunda clase**(archivo java).

```
public class AndroidImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context mContext;

AndroidImageAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return sliderImagesId.length;
}

private int[] sliderImagesId = new int[]{
        R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6,
        R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8, R.drawable.image9,

};

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object obj) {
    return v == ((ImageView) obj);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int i) {
    ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    mImageView.setImageResource(sliderImagesId[i]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(mImageView, 0);
    return mImageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int i, Object obj) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) obj);
}
```